# WordPress (nested) Post query, loop per category and then per ACF

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

*I'll first tell my goal, than what I came up with so far.*

**My goal:**

- I've made a shortcode that works with VisualComposer.
- In VC I can check the categories for this posttype.
- The goal of the short code is to fist select and sort the posts per selected category.
- Second, to divide and sort per ACF. Say, "custom_field_1"
- Thirdly and last. to sort the posts alphabetically on "custom_field_2" and then on "custom_field_3".

---

**Example:**

- Cat 1

  - red

    - post 1
    - post 2
  - blue

    - post 3
    - post 4
- Cat 2

  - red

    - post 5
    - post 6
  - blue

    - post 7
    - post 8

---

Al right. I've tried it out myself first. And this is my code so far:

```
<?php
function productlist_sc($atts){?>

    <?php
    global $post;

    $categories_array = array();
    $thecategories = get_categories();
    foreach( $thecategories as $category ){
        $categories_array[] = $category->slug;
    }

    if($atts[ 'category' ]){
        $atts[ 'category' ] = explode( ",", $atts[ 'category' ] );
    }

    //collect values, combining passed in values and defaults
    $values = shortcode_atts(array(
            'category' => ''
        ),$atts);

    $categories = get_categories( array(
            'orderby' => 'name',
            'parent'  => 0,
            'slug'    => $values['category']
        ) );

    $current = get_the_ID($post->ID);
    $cargs = array(
        //'child_of'      => 0,
        'orderby'       => 'name',
        'parent'   => 0,
        'order'         => 'ASC',
        'hide_empty'    => 1
        //'taxonomy'      => 'category', //change this to any taxonomy
    );

    // first sort all selected posts per category
    foreach ( $categories as $tax ) :



        // List posts by the terms for a custom taxonomy of any post type
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'products',
            'orderby' => 'ASC',
            'posts_per_page'=>-1,
            'category_name' => $tax->slug
        );


    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>
            <?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>

                <h2>Internal ID: <?php echo $tax->name; ?></h2><?php

    // second sort all selected posts per custom_field_1
    $mykey_values = get_post_custom_values( 'custom_field_1' );
    foreach ( $mykey_values as $key => $value ) :
        ?><h3><?php the_field('custom_field_1'); ?></h3>

                    <div class="rtt_prod_table">

                <!-- the loop -->
                <?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

                            <div>
                                <?php if( get_field('custom_field_1') || get_field('custom_field_2') || get_field('custom_field_3') ): ?>
                                    <ul>
                                        <?php if( get_field('custom_field_2') ): ?>
                                            <li>
                                                <?php the_field('custom_field_2'); ?>
                                            </li>
                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                        <?php if( get_field('custom_field_3') ): ?>
                                            <li>
                                                <?php the_field('custom_field_3'); ?>
                                            </li>
                                        <?php endif; ?>

                                    </ul>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <?php endwhile; ?> <!-- end of the loop -->

                <div><!-- end .accord-content -->
            </div>
            <?php wp_reset_postdata();
    endforeach; //  custom_field_1
?>
            <?php else : ?>
                <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php

    endforeach; /* end $tax */ ?>

<?php
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so I've found the answer. 
I'll post it here for anyone looking for a solution. :)

Steps:

- needed an array with all the unique values within "field 1"
- ran an post query for each post, grabbed the value of "field 1" and put in an array
- filtered all the duplicates
- alphabetized the array
- run a foreach in the array:

This is the code I added to the code above

```
$stack = array();

// query
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'products',
    'orderby' => 'ASC',
    'posts_per_page'=>-1,
    'category_name' => $tax->slug
);

// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();

        if( get_field('custom_field_1') ): 
            $stack[] = get_field('custom_field_1');
        endif;
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
}   

$result = array_unique($stack);
sort($result);

foreach ( $result as $tax2 ) :
     // run you code here
endforeach;
```

Have a great day boys and girls!